# Calling method asynchronously in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm trying to create Video To Gif converter using [WPF MediaKit (MediaDetector class)](http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WPFMediaKit/WPFMediaKit/DirectShow/MediaPlayers/MediaDetector.cs) library to extract video frame by time. I wanna to run `StartButton_OnClick` method asynchronously using async/await.

I'm using the following code:

```
private async void StartButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_openFile != null &&
        !String.IsNullOrEmpty(SaveToBox.Text))
    {
        await new LocalVideoConverter(_openFile.FileName, _from*1000, _to*1000,
            SaveToBox.Text, InterpolationMode.Low, new System.Drawing.Size(320, 240))
            .StartConverting();
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Choose video file and enter path for Gif");
}
```

`StartConverting()` method:

```
public override Task StartConverting()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Encoder.Start(GifPath);
        Encoder.SetDelay(Ival);
        Encoder.SetRepeat(0);
        for (double i = From; i < To; i += Ival)
        {
            var frame = GetFrame(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(i));
            frame = ResizeImage(frame);
            AddFrame(frame);
        }
        Encoder.Finish();   
    });
}
```

`GetFrame(TimeSpan ts)` method:

```
protected override Image GetFrame(TimeSpan ts)
{
    var bitmapSource = _mediaDetector.GetImage(ts);
    using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
        enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));
        enc.Save(outStream);
        return new Bitmap(outStream);
    }
}
```

Also MediaDetector class has `public unsafe BitmapSource GetImage(TimeSpan position)` method.

---

When I click on the StartButton, I get an System.InvalidOperationException with message **"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it"**
in this line of `GetImage()` method ([look this](http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WPFMediaKit/WPFMediaKit/DirectShow/MediaPlayers/MediaDetector.cs))

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_filename))
```

I the beginner in multi-threaded programming. How I can to solve this problem?

P.S. Sorry for my not good English:-)

Comment: Pretty sure that the exception is just one line before, where  [Dispatcher.VerifyAccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.verifyaccess.aspx) is called. It checks if the method call is allowed from the current thread, which apparently is not the case here. You may get around that limitation by synchronously executing the GetImage method in the Dispatcher thread, i.e. passing it to a [Dispatcher.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx) call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to get around `async`/`await` by using `BeginInvoke`. Since it's WPF, I guess you could write

```
 private void StartButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    if (_openFile != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(SaveToBox.Text)) {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate() {
            LocalVideoConverter lvc =  new LocalVideoConverter(_openFile.FileName, _from*1000, _to*1000,
            SaveToBox.Text, InterpolationMode.Low, new System.Drawing.Size(320, 240));
            lvc.StartConverting();
        }));
    } else
        MessageBox.Show("Choose video file and enter path for Gif");
}
```

`BackgroundWorker` might be possible as well, although I'd not recommend it.